# Storing single_tag_title in variable

Tags: wordpress, variables, tags, echo, archive

In Wordpress, the following will echo the currently chosen tag in an archive listing:

```
single_tag_title();
```

Does anybody know how to store it in a variable, so that i can echo out the same string using an ordinary php variable like this:

```
echo $tagSlug; //This shows the same string as the single_tag_title() function
```

I have tried this:

```
$tagSlug = single_tag_title();
echo $tagSlug;
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

single_tag_title accepts two arguments.  $prefix and $display.  $prefix sets the string which should be echoed/returned before the tag, and $display determines whether the tag is echoed or returned as a variable.  See [the documentation here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/single_tag_title).

```
$tagSlug = single_tag_title("", false);
echo $tagSlug;
```