# What is the correct syntax to echo a variable within a PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, syntax

I want to dynamically get the current category page title and use it to display some posts on the category pages in Wordpress.

```
<h1><?php single_cat_title(); ?></h1>
```

Correctly generates the current category, which is Stockholm, so appears as

## Stockholm

And if I type Stockholm manually into the array below, the correct posts are displayed.

```
<?php $posts = get_posts(array(
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_type'         => 'handelser',
    'category_name' => 'Stockholm',
    'meta_key'  => 'datum',
    'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'     => 'DSC',
));
if( $posts ): ?>
```

However it needs to work dynamically. I have tried the following code and it does not work:

```
<?php $catname = single_cat_title();
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_type'         => 'handelser',
    'category_name' => $catname,
    'meta_key'  => 'datum',
    'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'     => 'DSC',
));
if( $posts ): ?>
```

Grateful for any assistance.

Comment: Sorry, but it is completely unclear what you ask. To me this reads as if you expect the execution of the script to alter the script code on the fly?

Comment: @arkascha thank you for your comment. I have completely reformatted the question in order to make it clearer. I'm a total beginner with PHP by the way ;)

Comment: You should use `get_queried_object()` or `get_queried_object_id()` after doing the proper validation then use the term ID or slug in your WP Query.

Comment: In a similar fashion, [`single_tag_title()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16196481/2943403) has the same syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here, on Stack Exchange: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/245895/on-category-page-get-name-of-category-as-a-string

The correct code is:

```
<?php $posts = get_posts(array(
  'posts_per_page'    => -1,
  'post_type'         => 'handelser',
  'category_name' => single_cat_title( '', false ),
  'meta_key'  => 'datum',
  'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
  'order'     => 'DSC',
 ));

 if( $posts ): ?>
```

Comment: This is confusing ... 1. whether you store the return value of a function call into a variable and then use that variable when setting up an array comes out with exactly the same result than using the function call itself while setting up the variable. So the last code snippet in your question clearly works _if the function call returns what you want, the string "Stockholm". Which is what I think the actual issue here is, because in the code snippet here in the answer you call the function completely different suddenly with two runtime arguments.

Comment: @arkascha, I don't even know what runtime arguments do, I just copied them from the example on stackexchange. I tried removing them and it stopped working so they must be doing something important :) In any case, it's all working now, but thank you for your input!

Comment: What I tried to point out to you is that your first attempt (with the variable) should work perfectly well, _if you call the function as it is meant to be called, so with those arguments_ ... The issue is not how to setup an array. But how to use that framework the function belongs to. Which you never even told us about ...

Comment: In general: I would expect that you receive an error when calling that function _without_ arguments. To be sure you'd have to take a look into the documentation of the framework or library you are using, where that function comes from. Did you take a look into your http server's error log file? That should _always_ be the first place where you look if you experience something strange in web programming with PHP ...